# Is it possible to Use sqlite for website which is build in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite

I have website which i am building using html and javascript but due to lot of data i want to use local data base which will be with files so that i can access and retrieve data easily is there way to make sqlite data base and access in html web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use SQLite with javascript using sql.js refer below link:

http://badassjs.com/post/18857332551/sql-js-sqlite-compiled-to-javascript-via-emscripten

here is a start up tutorial: http://badassjs.com/post/18857332551/sql-js-sqlite-compiled-to-javascript-via-emscripten

Comment: where will be this data base place inside root folder to access

Comment: yes you can place database on root folder and be sure to write correct path of accessing your database.